# My TableView is showing up above plotted place

Tags: ios, tableview

So I have a `UITableView` that's showing up way above it's plotted place. Basically I have 2 `tableviews` and other stuff in this `scroll view`. Here's a picture of the problem:

[image: A picture of my problem]

Comment: Check the frame coordinates for the UITableView

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this was placed directly in the XIB file? Make sure that the scroll views and table views were placed correctly. That's all I can say. If they were placed in the code, then make sure your coordinates are correct.

Comment: They're placed directly in the XIB and placed correctly. How can this even happen?